# i want filter for "Unitprice" and "ProductID"

Tags: json, kendo-ui

I WANT FILTER FOR "`UnitPrice`" AND "`ProductID`"

This is the sample, you want more

using the jsfiddle link

hen the jsfiddle for  more detail & work my program in that

```
 //change event


    $("#category").keyup(function () {
        var selecteditem = $('#category').val();
        var kgrid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        selecteditem = selecteditem.toUpperCase();
        var selectedArray = selecteditem.split(" ");
        if (selecteditem) {
 });
            var orfilter = { logic: "or", filters: [] };
            var andfilter = { logic: "and", filters: [] };
            $.each(selectedArray, function (i, v) {
                if (v.trim() == "") {
                }
                else {
                    $.each(selectedArray, function (i, v1) {
                        if (v1.trim() == "") {
                        }
                        else {
                            orfilter.filters.push({ field: "ProductName", operator: "contains", value:v1 },
                                                  { field: "QuantityPerUnit", operator: "contains", value:v1});
                            andfilter.filters.push(orfilter);
                            orfilter = { logic: "or", filters: [] };
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
            kgrid.dataSource.filter(andfilter);
        }
        else {
            kgrid.dataSource.filter({});
        }

    });
```

I WANT FILTER FOR "`UnitPrice`" AND "`ProductID`"

visit

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Naka3/38/)

This is the sample, you want more

using the jsfiddle link

when the jsfiddle for  more detail & work my program in that

Comment: Please include an example of what you have already tried and also an example of your existing code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter for "UnitPrice" and "ProductID" column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802898/filter-for-unitprice-and-productid-column)